# What does & mean while passing string or vector to function?

Tags: c++

what is the purpose of using & while passing string or vector to a function by reference like this

```
int function(string & x){
return 0;
}
```

or

```
int function(vector<int>&x){
return 0;
}
```

why it shows error while using *.

Comment: Any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), tutorial or class should have taught you about *references*.

Comment: `why it shows error while using *`, what do you mean, what error?

Comment: As for the error when using `*`, here you need to learn more about *pointers* and how they work.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass reference with & ,you pass the actual data rather than passing a copy of data . Change you do in the vector is done on actual vector.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference i.e. using the `&` means you get access to the actual instance you passed to the function, in your case the `vector` or the `string`. Changes to the variable inside the function will also reflect outside the scope of your function.

thus,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int function(std::string & x) {
  x = "Hello Function!";
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::string my_string("Hello World!");
  function(my_string);                 // Pass by reference
  std::cout << my_string << std::endl; // Will print "Hello Function"
  return 0;
}
```